# Javascript solution for setting url based on two radio groups selections

Tags: javascript, jquery, button, radio-button

I wish to set a button link based on the selections made from two radio groups. I tried to set variants in javascript so that the link changes based on which two radio buttons are checked. I have been unable to find a solution.

```js
$('#product-options-form input[type="radio"]').click(function() {

  // There are 40 total variants, one is used for testing purposes
  var g1 = $("#variant_79").is(":checked") && $("#quantity_50").is(":checked");

  var addr = "";
  if (g1) {
    addr = "https://cruxstickers.com/product/2x2-50/";
  } else {
    addr = "www.google.com";
  }
  
  $("#product-options-form a").attr('href', addr);
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="variant-options" class="options">
<li><input type="radio" id="variant_79" name="variant_id" value="79" readonly=""><label for="variant_79"> 2" x 2"</label></li>
<li><input type="radio" id="variant_78" name="variant_id" value="78"><label for="variant_78"> 3" x 3"</label></li>
</ul>

<div id="quantities" class="product-option-group">
<legend>Select a quantity</legend>
<ul id="variant-quantities" class=" options radio"><li class="checked quantity-item"><span class="table-cell"><input type="radio" id="quantity_50" readonly="" name="quantity" value="50">
<label for="quantity_50" class="checked quantity"> 50</label></span></li>
<li class=" quantity-item"><span class="table-cell"><input type="radio" id="quantity_100" readonly="" name="quantity" value="100"><label for="quantity_100" class=" quantity"> 100</label></span></li>
<li class=" quantity-item"><span class="table-cell"><input type="radio" id="quantity_200" readonly="" name="quantity" value="200"><label for="quantity_200" class=" quantity"> 200</label></span></li>

</ul>
</div>

<div id="product-details-continue">
<a href="" onclick='myFunction()' id="myLink"><button type="submit" id="continue" class="button large primary block">Continue</button></a>
</div>
```

There are 40 total urls between the 4 size options and 10 quantity options. I have been googling and googling but I am unable to comprehend a solution to this. Any and all help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Rather than post a massive amount of html and *__Javascript__* (not Java), can you make a basic example showing what you want to do and explain what is going wrong?  Just a [MCVE]

Comment: Yes, I will work on that now.

Comment: Once you've edited the snippet in the question, click the `Run code snippet` button to make sure it actually runs ;)

Comment: I've minimized the code - but the error remains. It says the error is at lineno 32, but neither my html or java sections have that many lines! How can I fix it?

Comment: I've fixed the issue that was causing the error.  You had `.click(myFunction() { });` which you can't do.  It's either an anonymous function... `.click(function() {});` or a function defined elsewhere... `function myFunction() {};` `.click(myFunction);`

Comment: That did get rid of the error - thanks for that!

Comment: Okay, so do you want a button or a link?  At the moment you have a link with a button inside it, and it's a submit button at that which has a default action that may be causing a problem.

Comment: I would like a button that has its URL assigned by the radio options selected. The button inside the link bit of code was inherited from a webpage I was trying to copy, so I don't know why it is that way.

Comment: Buttons do not have Urls, so it sounds like you need a click handler for the button, and just make that check the radios when it's clicked.  I'll put something together for you.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than change a value every time the radio selections change, just handle the button click and check the values there.  At that point, build the URL based on the selected radios...

```js
$("#product-details-continue").click(function() {

  var addr = "https://cruxstickers.com/product/" +
      $("input[type=radio][name=variant_id]:checked").val() + "-" +
      $("input[type=radio][name=quantity]:checked").val();

  alert(addr);

  // change the addr to relevant URLs and do this instead...
  // location.href = addr;
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="variant-options" class="options">
<li><input type="radio" id="variant_79" name="variant_id" value="2x2" readonly=""><label for="variant_79"> 2" x 2"</label></li>
<li><input type="radio" id="variant_78" name="variant_id" value="3x3"><label for="variant_78"> 3" x 3"</label></li>
</ul>

<div id="quantities" class="product-option-group">
<legend>Select a quantity</legend>
<ul id="variant-quantities" class=" options radio"><li class="checked quantity-item"><span class="table-cell"><input type="radio" id="quantity_50" readonly="" name="quantity" value="50">
<label for="quantity_50" class="checked quantity"> 50</label></span></li>

<li class=" quantity-item"><span class="table-cell"><input type="radio" id="quantity_100" readonly="" name="quantity" value="100"><label for="quantity_100" class=" quantity"> 100</label></span></li>
<li class=" quantity-item"><span class="table-cell"><input type="radio" id="quantity_200" readonly="" name="quantity" value="200"><label for="quantity_200" class=" quantity"> 200</label></span></li>

</ul>
</div>

<button id="product-details-continue">continue</button>
```

Comment: Thank you for this, but please bear with me. I am still unsure which sections of the javascript need to be updated with my urls. I was using https://cruxstickers.com/product/2x2-50/ as the page I wish to navigate to for var g1. The else option could be my homepage www.cruxstickers.com.  Where do these values go?

Comment: Refresh the page - I did change it to use URLs.

Comment: Please don't edit the answer.  If you have a question then post a comment.

Comment: Okay - I edited www.cruxstickers.com/z-test-z/ to host the edited html at the top of the post. Nothing happens when continue is clicked no matter what buttons are selected. https://jsfiddle.net/masonmjez/8r7u2f2t/1/ also has the same code hosted in it, and an embedded page is created here. Does the embedded page notification signify the code is working?

Comment: Oops - think I meant to edit my own post, not your answer.

Comment: Please don't edit the question either.  It's not meant to show any progress - it's the question, not the answer.  If you need to try something then try it elsewhere.

Comment: Okay, I've modified it to what I think you're trying to do.  If you change the values of the variant radios so that they're `2x2`, `3x3` etc then that will now build the URL for you, without you having a bunch of if statements, one for each combination.  Is that what you're trying to do?

Comment: Yes! That is exactly what I am attempting to do. When running the code here on stackoverflow the embedded pages look perfect. How should I implement the javascript on my page? I tried to add it to my html between <script> tags but that seems to halt it from working.

Comment: I am using wordpress if that means anything for implementing this bit of javascript

Comment: I'm not a Wordpress user, so can't really help with that.  Have a read of this... https://www.godaddy.com/garage/3-ways-to-insert-javascript-into-wordpress-pages-or-posts/  It does mention that custom script tags are disabled by default, but tells you how to enable them.

Comment: None of those options of adding the javascript seems to work for me.

Comment: Sorry, I can't help with that.  Like I said, I'm not a Wordpress user.  You should do some thorough searching and then if you still can't get any Javascript to run on your site ask another question on here.

Comment: Well, I'm confident that the answer you provided is correct - I am just still having an issue adding the javascript. I'll be asking another question so I can hopefully come back and mark this as answered.